# Display items in a list containing a specific name - flutter

Tags: list, dart, flutter, contains

In this list, I want to display out all the items that contains this specific name.

My list items: ['US', 'SG', 'US']

```
print(list.contains("US"));
```

Using .contains() returns me a true or false but it doesn’t return me the list of strings that contains that. I want to only extract out the items that has 'US' from the list. In this case, there's 2 of it. Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try doing it the following way -

```
List<String> myList = ['US', 'SG', 'US'];
print(myList.where((item) => item.contains("US")));
```

You can also display it directly inside a `Text` widget in the following way -

```
Text(
   myList.where((item) => item.contains("US")).join(" "),
   //The join function joins the elements of the Iterable into a single string with the separator provided as an argument.
),
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

To display each of the word separately as a list you can display them inside a `Column` in the following way -

```
Column(
  children: myList.map((value) {
    if(value.contains("US")){
      return Text(value,);
    } else {
      return Container();
      //Return an empty Container for non-matching case
    }
  }).toList(),
)
```

The same thing can be used inside a `ListView` instead of `Column` if you want it to be scrollable.

Comment: it works but since there's two US it displays as 1 text that contains "US". i want to be able to display 2 of the US word in a list

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can refer to the **Update** section for your required use case.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Comment: What if its a list of object like `[{id:1, country: USA}, {id:2, country: India}, {id:3, country: Japan}]` and I want to do something like, `myList.contains('USA')` ? Is there a proper way?

Comment: You can use `List().indexWhere((element) => {})`. It takes a matching function where you provide the criteria. It returns a positive index if the element is preset else it returs -1. You can check [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) link for more help.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
  var myList = ['US', 'SG', 'US'];
  myList.forEach((w){
    if(w == "US")
      print(w);
  });
```

To show:

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  var myList = ['US', 'SG', 'US'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: myList.where((w) => w == "US").map((w) => Text(w)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

or for a single line display use, `Text` instead of `Column` widget mentioned above

```
Text(myList.where((w) => w.contains("US")).join(" "))
```

Comment: the first method works but how do i display it instead of printing it?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using "list.contains". It will only show the list exist or not , If you want to print the value you have to use follow :

```
var fruits = [‘banana’, ‘pineapple’, ‘watermelon’];fruits.forEach((fruit) => print(fruit)); // => banana pineapple watermelon
```

If you want to print just banana then you can use this

```
var fruits = [‘banana’, ‘pineapple’, ‘watermelon’];fruits.(fruit) => print(fruit[0]); // => banana
```

Comment: but i want to only print the value that contains banana for example. not all ><